# java mongodb driver no exception thrown on duplicate keys

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongo-java, mongotemplate

I'm using `spring framework` with `mongoTemplate`. bean initiation:

```
public
@Bean
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    mongoTemplate.setWriteResultChecking(WriteResultChecking.EXCEPTION);

    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

in short this code does not fail on duplicate key

```
collection= mTemplate.getCollection("col");
try {
        final WriteResult writeResult = collection.insert(edge);

} catch (DuplicateKeyException e) {
        log.warn("@error> edge already exists");

        return null;
}
```

`writeResult._lastErrorResult` is not null and has the relevant errors.

the document i'm trying to insert: 
Also I've tried to catch `Exception e` without success.

```
collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject("a", 1).append(, 1), unique);
DbObject edge = new BasicDBObject("a", "123").append("b", "345");
```

Comment: Please post the document that you tried inserting and a snapshot of the collection with the relevant id in question.

Comment: Try setting the WriteConcern to `SAFE`.http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html. It seems that the driver is not waiting for an acknowledgement from the primary server.

Comment: yeah that did the trick. i thought setting WriteresultChecking.EXCEPTION is enough. anyhow `SAFE` will probably going to be deprecated soon so should use `WriteConcern.ACKNOWLEDGED`

Comment: btw @BatScream you are more than welcome to add an answer which i will accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the `WriteConcern` of the MongoDB driver to [Acknowledged](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/WriteConcern.html#ACKNOWLEDGED).

From the docs,

> Write operations that use this write concern will wait for
>   acknowledgement from the primary server before returning. Exceptions
>   are raised for network issues, and server errors.